# Corrupted heap despite correct allocation and deallocation

Tags: fortran, gfortran, petsc

Here's an interesting problem that doesn't seem to have an obvious solution. After allocating a pointer to be a 16 element long `PetscReal` vector, filling it with data, and pulling the data from it, on `deallocate()` this error is thrown:

```
*** Error in `./myprogram': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x000000001930d8e0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f85076667e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80dfb)[0x7f850766fdfb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f850767353c]
...
```

I'm completely stumped on how this error could arise, given the way the array is crashes around is set up.

Here are all snippets of code related to this problem:

```
PetscReal, allocatable :: adj_temp_area(:), adj_local_area(:)
PetscInt :: temp_int, rec_local_tri

...do unrelated stuff...

rec_local_tri = int(sum(vec_ptr-1))
allocate(adj_local_area(rec_local_tri))
print*,rec_local_tri ! prints out '16'

temp_int=int(maxval(vec_ptr))
allocate(adj_temp_area(temp_int))
print*,temp_int ! prints out '4'

do i=1,grid%num_pts_local
    ...do stuff...
    call MatGetRow(grid%adjmatrix_area,grid%vertex_ids(i)-1,ncols,PETSC_NULL_INTEGER,adj_temp_area,ierr);CHKERRQ(ierr)
    adj_local_area(pos2+1:pos2+temp_int2) = adj_temp_area(2:temp_int)
enddo

print*, adj_local_area ! prints out 16 element array, filled with correct values

! CRASHES HERE!
deallocate(adj_local_area)
```

Several things:

1. `adj_local_area` is filled properly and its bounds are not overwritten. If you print out the literal value of the line where the array is filled, you see this:

   ```
    adj_local_area(           1 :           2 ) = adj_temp_area(2:           3 )
    adj_local_area(           3 :           5 ) = adj_temp_area(2:           4 )
    adj_local_area(           6 :           7 ) = adj_temp_area(2:           3 )
    adj_local_area(           8 :           9 ) = adj_temp_area(2:           3 )
    adj_local_area(          10 :          12 ) = adj_temp_area(2:           4 )
    adj_local_area(          13 :          14 ) = adj_temp_area(2:           3 )
    adj_local_area(          15 :          15 ) = adj_temp_area(2:           2 )
    adj_local_area(          16 :          16 ) = adj_temp_area(2:           2 )
   ```
2. Several other arrays are allocated, filled, and deallocated in the same way. There are no problems. If I comment out the `deallocate(adj_local_area)`, the code runs fine, until it tries to exit the subroutine and clear the heap - and it crashes with the same message.
3. I initially thought it was a type thing (i.e., `real*8` getting written into a `real*4` vector, say) but values being put into the array are all `PetscReal`, the same type as the vector itself (`PetscReal` is compiled as `real*4` for my configuration, I believe).

Any ideas? Let me know if you need more code and I can provide it.

Comment: Please provide a minimal but complete program that demonstrates the problem. Snippets are usually insufficient and misleading.

Comment: What is `temp_int2` and what are its values? Is it even declared or assigned values? `temp_int` is varying within the loop according to you but you've only shown the first value assigned outside the loop. As Steve implies, it's what we can't see that matters.

Comment: You say `...do unrelated stuff...`, so take it out! Does the error still occur? This is the debugging process you should be going through yourself.

Comment: That can be a buffer overflow *anywhere* in the program. A [mcve] is necessary. Which debugging flags and sanitizations do you use?